# Issue with Spring MVC - dispatcher problem

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have a problem using Spring MVC. Please keep in mind that I read about 15 topics asking the same question, and none of them gave me the answer. I'm kind of lost right now.

First of all, my code was smoothly working before I modified few functions in different layers. Then, when I try to log my page, I get a warn which is :

```
WARN (org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound) - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/bo/newsletter/accueil] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

All subjects I read were talking about modifying the web.xml file, which I tried. Without success.

Simply have my

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/newsletter/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

, which, as I said, worked properly few modifications ago.

So I tried to comment all my code, except the function that simply displays the main view. So I commented Controller, Service, DAO, SQLMapper. Still doesn't work.

The strange thing is that it works as a charm if I change my url path "[...]/newsletter/home" (which is my desired url) to "[...]/actualites/newsletter/home" ("actualites" being a path working, "actualites/home" for example).

Comment: Your mapping is for `/newsletter` but the URI in the error message starts `/bo` - is there another part of your configuration that accounts for this?

Comment: What is the application context path?

Comment: Tomcat is infamous for adding a context path by default to the URL. (In your case "Actualities") Have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375275/how-to-set-context-path-in-tomcat-so-one-could-enter-the-site-without-appending

Comment: @MTCoster yup, that's normal, it's because the basic path here is localhost:8080/bo/ ; every url (including "actualites", which is the one who works) begin by that prefix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution few days ago.

I misunderstood how annotations were supposed to work. My NewsletterController being annoted by @Controller, I placed @GetMapping, @DeleteMapping, etc. instead of @RequestMapping and then placing the type of request.

Thanks for helping anyway ! Strange error that popped tho, hope the solution'll help some :)